# How to wait for lottie animation to finish then do something

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, lottie

I am learning Xamarin.Forms

I would like to continue some action once my Lottie Anymation finish to play

Here is my xaml code :

```
 <forms:AnimationView Grid.Column="1" IsVisible="False"
                                x:Name="MyYesAddWordAnim"     
                                Animation="YesAddAnim.json"
                                RepeatMode="Infinite"  
                                HeightRequest="40"
                                WidthRequest="40"
                                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                            ClassId="2">

                            </forms:AnimationView>
```

Here is my code :

```
 void OnYesAddWord()
    {

        //start my animation
        MyYesAddWordAnim.IsVisible = true;
        MyYesAddWordAnim.PlayAnimation();


        //Do something here 


        //Wait for animation finished then Hide my animation
        MyYesAddWordAnim.IsVisible = true;


    }
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look at the [docs](https://github.com/Baseflow/LottieXamarin), `AnimationView` has an `OnFinishedAnimation` event handler